# Pycharm site-packages folder marked red and modules cannot be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pycharm, python-import

I have installed some files (`pygame`, `python-docx`) through `pip`. They appear in `pycharm` in the `site-packages` folder, but I cannot import anything from that folder. I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. The site-packages folder and sub-folders all appear as red.

Any ideas what I should do?

I have `python 3.7` and `pycharm community edition 2018.2.3`

Comment: Add path of site-packages folder in path variable. So that it will be accessible from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check if your current project interpreter is correct: you should see the path to your python environment where all packages are installed
as shown in the picture.

[python interpreter path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s53Bh.png)

Answer (score 1):

If your site-packages folder is marked red,

1. go to settings (Ctrl + Alt + S)
2. Select Project: "Your Project Name"
3. Select Python Interpreter
4. Double click on pip
5. Type in pygame in the searchbar
6. Finally download the package
7. Now you can import pygame