# How to set library root correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm, openpyxl

OS: Windows 10

I am new to python (and programming) and use this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/_uQrJ0TkZlc?t=14055

My problem starts at the time-print by installing openpyxl via pip:
I can install openpyxl sucessfully but after that I can not use it via:

`import openpyxl`
I get:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'`

Now the video shows me the path where openpyxl should be installed:
-External Libraries\Python 3.7\site-packages *library root*\site-packages
where it should be: https://ibb.co/vH1cCXY

But my *library root* is:
-External Libraries\Python 3.7\Python *library root* 
And so I find openpyxl inside:
-External Libraries\Python 3.7\Python *library root*\Lib\site-packages
The folder site-packages and its contents are red.
where it is instead: https://ibb.co/ydBbSGP.png

Somehow my *library root* is not set correctly. But I can not find a solution.

This Question is similar to:
[Pycharm site-packages folder marked red and modules cannot be imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52621583/pycharm-site-packages-folder-marked-red-and-modules-cannot-be-imported)

So I checked my interpreter setting but can not find anything noticeable:
interpreter setting: https://ibb.co/bvg7fCb

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

My terminal in Pycharm is not by default set to the virtual environment (venv)
The instructor in youtube has: `(venv) Path:`
But I have instead `Path:`

So Pycharm installs everything inside my Python 3.7 but it looks inside the virtual enviroment if I run my code. And that can not work.

By typing `venv\Scripts\activate` I set my Terminal to the virtual environment `(venv) Path:`

Last step was uninstalling openpyxl with `Path:` and reinstalling it with the `(venv) Path:`
Now openpyxl is in the correct directory and everything works fine.