# [pycharm]Can't read pips in 'site-packages'...and the folder is 'red'

Tags: python

I downloaded and installed 'python-docx' pip.
It's been installed in the path of 'External Libraries -> Python 3.7... -> Lib ->site-packages' .

But when I type 'import python-docx' on the python file, this pip can't be found anywhere.
 And the folder 'site-packages' appears red color, while all other pip folders stays yellow. And all this red folder pips are not able to be accessed in the python file.

What should I do...

Before, same question was on here. ([Pycharm site-packages folder marked red and modules cannot be imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52621583/pycharm-site-packages-folder-marked-red-and-modules-cannot-be-imported))
 And people suggested solutions like "Try to check if your current project interpreter is correct: you should see the path to your python environment where all packages are installed as shown in the picture."
 But I don't understand what this means... What is 'checking' current project interpreter? What should I do exactly?

Comment: The `import python-docx` is syntax incorrect.

Comment: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen  I followed syntax you provided and it still doesn't work. It isn't matter of syntax. pycharm really can't read pips in the red folders.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen https://youtu.be/rfscVS0vtbw?t=13336
I'm just doing what he says. But what's done in his pycharm does not in mine. He does 'import docx' well, but 'docx' folder is red in my pycharm and can't be accessed.

Comment: is it running properly when pycharm run it?

Comment: @Reznik pycharm runs other codes or pips perfectly. But only when I try to access pips in the site-packages folder, It doesn't get anything.

Comment: Did you create a virtual env for this project?

Comment: @Reznik Didn't do such thing especially, unless pycharm did it as default. How can I do that?

Comment: Go to the pycharm settings and check which interpreter you are using

Comment: @Reznik   do you mean 'project interpreter'?
project interpreter path is "C:\users\NEWS1\Pycharm\Projects\Giraffe2\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
And there's two packages, 'pip  (version 19.0.3)' 'setuptools (version 40.8.0)'.
Which is the interpreter among these??

Comment: @Reznik   Here's additional interpreter paths
file://C:/Users/NEWS1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/DLLs
file://C:/Users/NEWS1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib
file://C:/Users/NEWS1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32
file://C:/Users/NEWS1/PycharmProjects/Giraffe2/venv
file://C:/Users/NEWS1/PycharmProjects/Giraffe2/venv/Lib/site-packages
jar://C:/Users/NEWS1/PycharmProjects/Giraffe2/venv/Lib/site-packages/setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg!/
file://C:/Users/NEWS1/PycharmProjects/Giraffe2/venv/Lib/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its seems like you use a virutal env here, you can read about it here [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

if want to using virutal env in your case you need to install the packages to your specific env, or you can use the python interprent you have on you computer, check your python interprer path and add it as an interpreter in the pycharm configuration

Comment: Wow.. Thank you SO much for your help. I solved it with the link you gave.